# Duplicate key error on non-primary key field

Tags: python, django

I am getting the follow error with django

> (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'building_id'")

Here is what the model looks like

```
class BuildingProgressComments(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    building = models.OneToOneField('Building')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Building progress notes'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.building)
```

I am trying to add multiple entries for a single building and the building field isn't a primary key so why wont this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: When I try and insert a new record with the same building

Comment: the broblem because of your OneToOneField .to change the field to foriegn key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused because you are using a ‘OneToOneField’ which will not allow you to create multiple entries for a ‘building_id’.

[Check out - Django Documentation - OneToOne fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

You want to use a ‘ForeignKey’ field to create multiple entries with the same ‘building_id’ just like you used on the ‘User’ field.

Here’s how it should look:

```
class BuildingProgressComments(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    building = models.ForeignKey('Building')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Building progress notes'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.building)
```

Comment: Although be careful, by Django 2.0, you will have to specify the `on_delete` argument to your `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thanks this works now, I should have known it would have been something simple. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
 To change your code:

From

```
building = models.OneToOneField('Building')
```

To

```
building = models.ForeignKey('Building')
```

Helful Tips: to know more about click here [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert multiple entries into a `OneToOneField`. Like its name implies, you can only have one entry for this type of field. Use a `ForeignKey` instead.